# Converting Different columns into rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, pivot-table

I have data in SQL Server that needs to be converted from columns into rows. Now although this question has been asked quite a lot in sometime, I was still facing some difficulty and hence I was wondering if someone can assist me.

Currently the format is as below.

[image]

The table format that is required and that will be very helpful will be;

[image]

So not only the PIVOT needs to be applied but I am not sure which SQL Query syntax will help to identify the Type. I have tried using CASE-WHEN with PIVOT but that really yield correct output.

Regards!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use CROSS APPLY query like below

<kbd>**[see working demo](http://rextester.com/JYN37628)**</kbd>

```
Select 
ProjectName,
v.*
from t
cross apply 
  (
   values 
    ('Plan',PlanStartDate,PlanEndDate),
    ('Actual',ActualStartDate, ActualEndDate)
  )v(type,StartDate, EndDate)
```

Comment: Thanks but there is no "Type" column. The Type needs to be identify from the column name. Hence PlanStartDate and PlanEndDate will have Type as "Plan". Same goes for "Actual"

Comment: So can there be many types of `Type` column data points which are to be calculated from other column's name using convention?

Comment: Romil N, Dhruv's answer is correct. He is not using a "type"column, instead he is creating it for you. Nice cross apply unpivot there.

Comment: That answer is really slick.  You're going to need to add a 'values' list for every type you want to include, but that's way better than the UNION query I would have given you.  This is the exact case the CROSS APPLY must be designed for; it would take some serious (and unreliable) monkeying to dynamically generate those columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  ;WITH CTE2(ProjectName,[Plan Start Date],[Plan End Date],[Actual Start Date],[Actual End Date])
   AS
    (
    SELECT 'PR-A','1/1/2006','1/4/2006','1/4/2007','1/5/2008' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'PR-B','1/1/2007','1/1/2008','4/4/2008','6/6/2008' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'PR-C','1/1/2004','1/1/2008','2/5/2001','2/2/2008'
    )

   SELECT Projectname, 
       'Plan'            AS [Type], 
       [Plan start date] AS [Start Date], 
       [Plan end date]   AS [End Date] 
   FROM   Cte2 

   UNION ALL 

   SELECT Projectname, 
       'Actual' AS [Type], 
       [Actual start date], 
       [Actual end date] 
   FROM   Cte2 
   ORDER  BY Projectname, 
          [Type] DESC
```

---

Demo :http://rextester.com/CQEBV76844